# Why am I getting an error next to the squigly brackets?

Tags: javascript, function

I should not be getting any errors when I run this code but I am and its right next to the squiggly brackets. I have changed things and moved things and altered the code but this error is always there:

```
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
var bosshp = 150;
var playhp = 100;
alert("You are going to fight a boss");
alert("You have 100hp while the boss has 150hp, you deal between 1 and 10 damage while he does between 1 and 15 damage.");
alert("You have two actions and two special abilities. Your moves are block, and attack. Blocking heals you for 5 while attacking attacks...Your special abilities are crit chance and dodge chance. There is a 25% chance to deal double damage and a 15% chance that you will dodge the bosses attack!");
alert("Ok " + name + ", You have to fight Gorlock, the monkey king. ");
do 
{
    var q = prompt("What will be your first move?\nEnter either 'block' or 'attack'");
    if (q === "block") 
    {
        playhp = playhp + 5;
    }
    else if (q === "attack") 
    {
        function attack ();
    }
}
 while (bosshp >= 0 || playhp >= 0);


function attack() {
    if ((Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)) < 16) {
        bosshp = bosshp - (Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) * 2);
    } else {
        bosshp = bosshp - (Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, say curly braces, not squiggly brackets (although I knew what you meant, others may not).

Comment: Which curly brackets? We can't see your screen and we can't see any curly brackets

Answer (score 0):

because you are defining a function when you are really calling it

```
else if (q === "attack") 
{
    function attack ();
    ^^^^^^^^
}
```

remove the function

```
else if (q === "attack") 
{
    attack();
}
```

Use a tool like http://www.jshint.com/ or http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: +1. Note that the "function" keyword is used to define a function, not to call it. Besides using JSHint, I'd recommend learning the basics of the JS syntax before you code your game (this is intended as a friendly advice).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wtjo7rmw/ My code does not stop unless both hp values are negative. Why is that and how do  I get my || (or) t ofunction properly

Comment: because it says if this OR that is greater than zero. It does not say if that AND that is both greater than zero. The code is running exactly right, you want AND not OR